# kotlin safe/unsafe cast (redundant question mark?)

Tags: kotlin

I read the [Kotlin lang docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) and it addresses both of these cases:

Unsafe cast:

```
val x: String = y as String
```

Safe cast:

```
val x: String? = y as? String
```

but Kotlin seems to allow this as well (note the right most `?`:

```
val x: String? = y as? String?
```

Is the furthest most `?` redundant in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put yes. The reason being that `as?` is a nullable cast operator, meaning that if in your example `y` is null then the cast is not even tried (effectively, as you wrote, performing a safe cast). Only when `y` is not null, the cast is performed and therefore having `String` or `String?` has exactly the same effect, actually making `?` redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with João Dias answer, the `?` in `String?` is redundant, you can check also the code behind by decompile the kotlin bytecode. Both `as? String` and `as? String?` produce the same compiled code as follows

```
String var10001 = this.y;
if (!(var10001 instanceof String)) {
   var10001 = null;
}

this.x = var10001;
```